# WP Query not returning expected value

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got the below code to return a list of jobs that are marked as complete but don't have an invoice number inputted into the invoice_number text field yet. It returns nothing even though I've not inputted any invoice numbers yet.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'jobs',
    'posts_per_page'        => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'job_date',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job_status',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'complete' )
        ),
    ),
    'meta_query' => array (
      'relation' => 'AND',
        array (
          'key' => 'invoice_number',
          'value' => '',
          'compare' => '='
        )
    )
));
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `meta_query` part you are explicitly looking for jobs with `invoice_number` equal to `''` (empty string).

However, when a meta (field & value) is not assigned to a post (in your case a job), it will not exist at all, so you need to use:

```php
    ...
    'meta_query' => array (
      'relation' => 'AND',
        array (
          'key' => 'invoice_number',
          'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    )
    ...
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/

Also, usually singular form is used for `post_type` values, so make sure that your current `"jobs"` value is actually correct.